# LoadCompleted event in WPF WebBrowser is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF `WebBrowser` control.

```
<WebBrowser Name="wbMap"></WebBrowser>
```

In the code behind, I am calling a function in the constructor where I am setting the navigation path and calling a script in the `LoadCompleted` event.

```
private void LoadMap()
{
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) return;
    //Get the application execution path
    String appdir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
    //Combine the application execution path with map file name
    String mapPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appdir, "MAP.html");
    //Navigate the browser to the above path
    wbMap.Navigate(mapPath);
    wbMap.LoadCompleted += wbMap_LoadCompleted;         
}

void wbMap_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    wbMap.InvokeScript("setLocation", "red");
}
```

This javascript function set a default location on a google map. But when I am invoking this in the `LoadCompleted` event, I cannot see the marker. Whereas, when I put a button and add this in the `Button.Click` event, the location is setting. How should I invoke this function?

Comment: I think that Load completed is for the HTML file to complete loading and not the javascript initialization which is called in the onLoad event of the document. So I am initializing the marker in the initialize() function. Am I right?